# How to check if the user is admin in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, admin

As a checklogin function in my Controller I have

```
public function checkLogin(Request $request)
    {
        //if the validation rule isn't passed it will be redirected to login form with validation error
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:3'
        ]);

        $user_data = array(
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->get('password'),
        );


        if (Auth::attempt($user_data)) {
            return redirect('/successlogin');
            //user will be redirected to successlogin method
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
            //by using back() he will be redirected to the previous location
        }
    }
```

And I added a `$table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);` column to my model
Also I've tried to make a middleware. Something like

IsAdmin.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()) {
        if (Auth::user()->is_admin) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return Redirect::to('successlogin');
    }
}
```

But it throws me an error
"Call to a member function send() on null"

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How do you determine if someone is Admin, do you have Roles/Permissions in place? Or just a column in your User model?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't mean to shout, I just really trying hard to fix it.I have just a column in my model

Comment: To make it easier for others to help please edit your question and add relevant information there. What is that column named, what type is it, what have you tried really hard to fix it.